# Java: Waiting on Get Method of ScheduledFuture

Tags: java, future

Please consider the following code:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    ScheduledFuture<?> future =
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(Dummy::iterate,
                                     0,
                                     1,
                                     TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1500);
    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    System.out.println("Getting the future...");
    future.get();
    System.out.println("Got the future...");
    System.out.println("Finished");
  }

  private static void iterate(){
    System.out.println("Iterating... counter is: " + counter++);
    try {
      TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(900);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Note that the `executor.awaitTermination(...)` command `future.get()` command are happening after 1500 ms, meaning in the middle of the `iterate()` method. 
This means that `awaitTermination(...)` will return false because the scheduled task hasn't finsihed yet.

Now, `future.get()` will wait forever. The task will finish and the service won't start other tasks, but yet the `get()` will never return.

A workaround is asking the future for `isDone()`, and only if it is done, asking for the result.

My question is what exactly is happening?
Looks like that if `shutDown()` happens in the during an iteration, the ScheduledThreadPool will somehow halt and, meaning there will be no future available. So why is this happening? I have looked at the documentation but couldn't find any reference indicating this issue. Is it possible that such scenario causes a future to not done, and later for the future to not be available?

Comment: Which value would the `ScheduledFuture.get()` return? The result of the first execution? The second?...

Comment: The future is `Future<?>`. I am only interested in any exception that might have happened during the execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace your :

```
future.get();
```

to something like:

```
future.get(2000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Then you see `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException` exception ocuur.
and this Exception thrown when a blocking operation times out. Blocking operations for which a timeout is specified need a means to indicate that the timeout has occurred. For many such operations it is possible to return a value that indicates timeout; when that is not possible or desirable then TimeoutException should be declared and thrown.

Comment: Also The Future.get() will return only after successful completion.

Comment: This is further noted in Future.get() documentation:Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.